# Not able to click on button in iframe window, but getting success while debugging

Tags: iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Not able to click on button element in iframe window, but getting success while debug.
While debugging I am successfully getting passed through action. Both the times(debugging and executing) UI(application) cannot see any actions performed.

Can Any one suggest this please. I have tried using giving waits. Xpath for button can not be wrong as Its successfully getting passed while debugging.

May be it a browser issue or something? I am using firefox browser

```
    waitforelementpresent(locator.login_email);
    click(locator.login_email);
    type(locator.login_email,email);
    click(locator.login_password);
    type(locator.login_password,password);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    click(locator.login_button); //This button I need to click
```

**Base Class**

```
    public static void click(By by) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, defaultWaitPeriod);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    driver.findElement(by).click();
}

    public static void type(By by, String type) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, defaultWaitPeriod);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    driver.findElement(by).clear();
    driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(type);
```

**Locators**

```
public By login_email=By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email ']");
public By login_password=By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password ']");
public By login_button=By.xpath("//form[@class='m-t  ng-dirty ng-valid-email ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required']//button");
```

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCxQ4.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to switch to that `iframe`?

Comment: Yes it successfully get switched and able to perform couple of actions

Comment: Can you share the code you used?

Comment: Shared the code, with html code image link for html source code

Comment: Try switching to frames, as I can't see any switchTo() statement in your code!
And also instead of adding wait conditions for each element, use



`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`